# How can I view Point Clouds?

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am using open source code called [ORB SLAM 2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2). As far as I know, ORB SLAM 2 does not save the map. So in order to save the points (point clouds), I have included a small code inside System.cc:

```
void System::CreatePCD(const string &filename){
    cout << endl << "Saving map points to " << filename << endl;

    vector<MapPoint*> vMPs = mpMap->GetAllMapPoints();

    // Create PCD init string
    std::string begin = std::string("# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format\nVERSON .7\n");
    begin += "FIELDS x y z\n";
    begin += "SIZE 4 4 4\n";
    begin += "TYPE F F F\n";
    begin += "COUNT 1 1 1\n";

    int width = vMPs.size();
    begin += "WIDTH ";
    begin += std::to_string(width);
    begin += "\nHEIGHT 1\n";
    begin += "VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0\n";
    begin += "POINTS ";
    begin += std::to_string(width);
    begin += "\nDATA ascii\n";

    // File Opening:
    ofstream f;
    f.open(filename.c_str());
    f << begin;

    // Write the point clouds:
    for(size_t i= 0; i < vMPs.size(); ++i){
        MapPoint *pMP = vMPs[i];
        if (pMP->isBad()) continue;
        cv::Mat MPPositions = pMP->GetWorldPos();
        f << setprecision(7) << MPPositions.at<float>(0) << " " << 
        MPPositions.at<float>(1) << " " << MPPositions.at<float>(2) << endl;
    }

    f.close();
    cout << endl << "Map Points saved!" << endl;

  }
}
```

As you can see, I have included all the necessary things for the PCL version 7. My newly created point cloud file looks like this:

```
# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSON .7
FIELDS x y z
SIZE 4 4 4
TYPE F F F
COUNT 1 1 1
WIDTH 1287
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 1287
DATA ascii
0.1549043 -0.3846602 0.8497394
0.01127081 -0.2949406 0.9007485
0.6072361 -0.3651089 1.833479
…
```

But whenever I try to visualize the file by running `pcl_viewer pointclouds.pcd` I get an error:

```
> Loading pointcloud.pcd [pcl::PCDReader::readHeader] No points to read
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PCD (Point Cloud Data) file format is [well documented](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php). At a first look your file seems to be correct, but there is a small typo (missing *I*) in your code:

```
std::string begin = std::string("# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format\nVERSON .7\n");
```

The code writes:

> VERSON .7

Correct would be:

> VERS**I**ON .7

A quick look in the [source code](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/pcd_io.cpp#L343) shows that the typo leads to an early exit because it matches no valid parameter. This means all following parameters, including *POINTS*, are ignored. The result will be the *No points to read* error.

Fix the typo and your file works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your format:

```
// Create PCD init string
std::string begin = std::string("# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format\nVERSON .7\n");
```

`VERSON` its being written instead of `VERSION` (it's missing an `I`).